# How to automatically increase version in csproj file after pipeline build

Tags: azure-devops, development-environment

wanted to ask for your advice on versioning packages or software apps. Lets say i have a build pipeline in Azure DevOps which increases the version of my package by 1 according to semantic versioning rules. when i build everything i use the params `/p:FileVersion=$(buildVersionNumber) /p:AssemblyVersion=$(buildVersionNumber) /p:Version=$(versionNumber)`  so my dlls have the needed versions and also my package in the feed looks fine.

The major and minor version items are set as pipeline variables and are used to build the version number. The patch is increased by using a counter:

```
- job: SetMainBuildNumber
  displayName: 'Set Build Number for main branch'
  dependsOn:
  - GetFileVersion

  variables:
    patch: $[counter(variables['minor'], variables['patchVer'] )]
  steps:
    - powershell: |
        Write-Host "##[debug]major was set to $(major)"
        Write-Host "##[debug]minor was set to $(minor)"
        Write-Host "##vso[build.updatebuildnumber]$(major).$(minor).$(patch)-main"
        Write-Host "##vso[task.setvariable variable=patch;isOutput=true]$(patch)"
      name: SetMainBuildNamePs
      displayName: 'Set Build Number (main)'
```

After the version is calculated it is set during build:

```
- task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
  displayName: 'Build $(projectName)'
  inputs:
    command: 'build'
    arguments: '-c $(buildConfiguration) --no-restore /p:FileVersion=$(buildVersionNumber) /p:AssemblyVersion=$(buildVersionNumber) /p:Version=$(versionNumber) /p:InformationalVersion=$(Build.BuildNumber)'
    projects: $(projectPath)
    feedsToUse: 'select'
    feedRestore: 'PipelinesTestFeed'
    verbosityRestore: 'Diagnostic' # Options: -, quiet, minimal, normal, detailed, diagnostic
    includeNuGetOrg: true
```

But how do i get the automatically generated version back to the source code? I tried to achieve this by using some sort of automatic commits but this seems a little bit hacky... What are the best practices for this usecase?

I have already tried this so far:

https://systemadminspro.com/automatic-version-number-management-with-azure-devops/

But this is cluttering my main branch history by adding a history entry after every commit

[image: main branch history after automatic version push to main branch]

Would it be possible to perform the following steps when merging a PR:

1. Check what version is already available on the main Branch
   Eg use Task to checkout main and get version from file with
   powershell -> then declare version as output vars
2. Compare with current version of file to be merged
3. If current version = main version -> Update version on pr branch and push
4. complete merge PR to main

Comment: Another thing i wanted to try is https://gist.github.com/manualbashing/524492e571f3cdbf0a007e54f000e1c2    but i'm not sure if i can update the pr branch with the version number that i got eg from the main branch and push it back so that it is integrated after review to the main branch...

Comment: You want to get the automatically generated version back to the source code; at the same time, you are afraid of adding a history entry to the source code after every commit. But these two things are actually the same thing, and I'm afraid there is no way to separate them. If you update the pr branch, when it is completed, it will also add a history entry to the source code. 

Maybe you could consider writing clear commit messages when pushing code back.

Comment: @MiaoTian-MSFT Hi there, thanx for your reply. Think i have to be more specific: I would like not to create version commit messages directly into the main branch.  When completing a pull request the PR is squashed so we see only the PR merge message in main history. I added a new screenshot above

Answer (score 0):

You should not care about commiting version to source code : you will introduce too much noise in git history, you can add tags, and should rely on commit messages to monitor your state of the software